# Doing some actions (setting language) before controller initializes in Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, globalization, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to set `Language` to my `controller` in `Web API` **(Doing Internationalization Globalization).**

I am writing an attribute called `SetLanguage` and decorate my `web-api controller` with it

Something like,

```
[SetLanguage]
public ServiceRequestController : ApiController
```

But the problem is this:

```
public class SetAcceptLanguageHeader : Attribute, IControllerConfiguration
    {
        public void Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
        {
            if (controllerSettings.Request.Headers.AcceptLanguage != null && controllerContext.Request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.Count > 0)
            {
                var culture = new CultureInfo(controllerContext.Request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.First().Value);
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
            }
        }
    }
```

But, I am not able to do this because I cannot access `Request` from `controllerSettings`.

(Though I know the idea of using a `BaseController` and overriding `Initialize` method to achieve the same, I am trying to use this `[SetLanguage]` Attribute`)

Any ideas how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using action filters like

```
public class SetLanguageAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //Use actionContext.Request to access your request
    }
}
```

This can then be used to decorate the action method with the [SetLanguage] attribute which can possibly set it to the culture as needed.

Comment: Is there a way to make this a class level attribute and access init?